# Java - public class constructor

Tags: java, class

I need explain on class.
What is constructor and how write it and what is public namecllase(){
Here all the variable 
}
How this is call?

Thank you

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Ok simple example 
You make one class that name is : Demo

```
class Demo{

}
```

Inner you make a constructer, that is what you call if you need it... look below

```
class Demo{
  public Demo(int num, String str)
  {
       int num;
       String str = "This is a parameterized constructor with number ";
       System.out.println(str + num);
  }
}
```

You can make more of them for example an empty constructer or with a defined value
Now you can call your class with that constructer something like that :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String strrrrr = "This is your value of variable int"
    int i = 99;
    Demo demo = new Demo(strrrrr, i);
}
```

So you can see that you console gives you message with your variable String strrrrr and int i 
I hope I could help you ;)

Comment: thank you, it's was helpful.

Comment: Only one thing I did not understand, if i have constructer Demo i need to write Before the constructor >> public/private int =0; and public/private String=""; ? because I've seen other codes listed in this, Is it necessary and if it changed anything? And what is meant in general?